# MySQL - How to separate out multiple table rows into one like query result

Tags: mysql

We have several tables that we need to pull data from based on the user_id.  Everything works great, except that now we've separated out the addresses and there can be more than one physical address location per user (up to 3 max).  We need to identify each of these addresses as a1, a2, a3, knowing that a2 and a3 are optional and may be null.

Here is the addresses table schema:

```
    $sql[] = "CREATE TABLE {$modules->tables->members_addresses} (
                id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                mailing tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                public tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
                address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                city varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                region_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                country_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                postalcode varchar(200) NOT NULL,
                date_created datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
                date_updated datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL
        ) {$modules->tables->charset_collate};";
```

Here is the query SQL that I have so far.  The problem with it is I get a separate result for each location (i.e. instead of wrapping a1-a3 into one query result, it is giving me separate query results):

```
SELECT p.*, concat( u1.meta_value, ' ', u2.meta_value ) as fullname, u1.meta_value as first_name, u2.meta_value as last_name, a.address, a.city, a.postalcode, case when p.certifications = '' then roles.name else concat( roles.name, ',', p.certifications ) end as certification, case when r.name is null then c.name else concat( r.name, ', ', c.name ) end as location, case when r.name is null then '' else r.name end as region, case when c.name is null then '' else c.name end as country
FROM modules_profiles p
LEFT JOIN moonlight_usermeta u1 ON p.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'first_name' 
LEFT JOIN moonlight_usermeta u2 ON p.user_id = u2.user_id AND u2.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN modules_members_addresses a ON p.user_id = a.user_id LEFT JOIN modules_roles roles ON roles.slug = p.certification 
LEFT JOIN modules_regions r ON r.id = a.region_id LEFT JOIN modules_countries c ON c.id = a.country_id 
WHERE p.user_id IN ( 1 )
ORDER BY p.user_id
```

What is the SQL to separate out a1, a2, and a3?  BTW I need a1.address, a1.city, a1.region, a1.country, a1.postalcode (and repeat for a2 and a3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the same table many times in a query

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, a1.*, a2.*, a3.*
FROM users AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses AS a1 ON a1.userId = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses AS a2 ON a2.userId = u.id AND a2.id < a1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses AS a3 ON a3.userId = u.id AND a3.id < a2.id
WHERE u.id = 1 AND a1.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM addresses WHERE userId = 1)
```

The `a1.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM addresses WHERE userId = 1)` is to get you the 'first' address first. It's often a bad idea to use ids for sequencing so you might want to implement a 'sequence' or 'preference' field in addresses.